# Python prints parts that are not identical in two strings

Tags: python-3.x, string

i try to do something like this:

```
a = "i am from Israel"
b = "i live in Switzerland"
```

Output:

```
"live", "am", "from", "Israel", "in", "Switzerland"
```

Because these parts do not appear in both strings.
how can i do that?

Comment: Show the code.  What's shown won't produce any output.

Comment: I wrote what I wanted the program to print

Comment: It sounds like you want a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) operation called [symmetric_difference](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference).

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a coding service.  Read the links and code it yourself.  If you have a problem, post the code.

Comment: what do you mean "SO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set()` and [symetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference):

```
a = "i am from Israel"
b = "i live in Switzerland"
c = set(a.split()) ^ set(b.split())
print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'Israel', 'Switzerland', 'am', 'from', 'in', 'live'}
```

Answer (score -1):

I liked the challenge, it's by no means a perfect answer but this is what i came up with.

```
a = "i am from Israel"
b = "i live in Switzerland"

a = a.split(" ")        # splitting the strings
b = b.split(" ")

for part in b:          # iterating over list
    try:
        a.remove(part)  # try to remove 
    except ValueError:  # if removing gives you an error it is not in it 
        a.append(part)  # add the part to list a

print(a)
```

outputs this for me:
`['am', 'from', 'Israel', 'live', 'in', 'Switzerland']`